# Global name 'lats' not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, global

I have executed this code and it worked fine but on a second run it brought up an error stating 'Global name lats not defined'.

Here I am trying to link two datasets together using the latitude and longitude and then to assign an ID to the one that is nearest to the place

How can I solve this?

```
Place['Dr_Address_No'] = -1

place_lats = place['Latitude']
place_lngs = place['Longitude']

Dr_locations = pd.read_csv("dr.csv")

dr_lats = dr_locations['latitude']
dr_lngs = dr_locations['longitude']

def get_nearest_dr(place_lats, place_lngs, dr_lats, dr_lngs):
    nearest_drs = []

    for placeID in range(lats.shape[0]):
        place_lat = lats.iloc[placeID]
        place_lng = lngs.iloc[placeID]

        lat_distances = (place_lat - dr_lats.iloc[:].values) ** 2
        lng_distances = (place_lng - dr_lngs.iloc[:].values) ** 2

        distance_vector = np.sqrt(lat_distances + lng_distances)

        closest_index = distance_vector.argmin()
        closest_dr = dr_locations.iloc[closest_index]
        dr_full = dr_address.iloc[closest_index]

        nearest_drs.append(dr_full['Dr No'])


    return pd.Series(nearest_drs)

Place['Dr_No'] = get_nearest_dr(place_lats, place_lngs, dr_lats, dr_lngs)

Place
```

Comment: there's no values `lats` or `lngs` anywhere in this code. So either you didn't post all the code properly or the error message is in fact correct and there is no Global value `lats` defined anywhere in this code so it is failing on this line `for placeID in range(lats.shape[0]):`

Comment: Yes @JamesRusso it is stating that as the error line. It was previously working, do you know how I could get round this?

Comment: if you do a find in that code there is clearly no variable defined as `lats`. It is most likely a typo since I do not see `lats` being define anywhere. `lats` is most likely supposed to be `place_lats` and you need to replace `lats` and `lngs` with `place_lats` and `place_lngs` respectively

Comment: Ask yourself, what is "lats"? Why is it missing? Was it previously present? SO is a terrible debugger. Either code is missing here, or you made a change you don't understand.

Comment: @JamesRusso I have changed all lats to place_lats and place_lngs but I am not getting the error
     numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: That means in one of the places you are calling `iloc` you are calling it on a decimal/float value instead of a numpy array, it's hard to say where that is happening/why exactly since you use that function multiple times. I'm assuming it's on `dr_lats` or `dr_lngs` since it's not failing on the `place_lats.shape[0]` call since it would if `place_lats` was `numpy.float64`

Comment: @JamesRusso I sorry I am new to python and jupyter notebook, what would you recommend to fix this new error?

Comment: what line is it occurring on? Whatever line it is occurring on, see what variable is trying to use `iloc`. That variable is a `numpy.float64` when it should be `numpy.array`. See how you are setting that variable originally and what is going wrong. You should research `how to debug` for future problems, here is one simple resource https://www.codementor.io/mattgoldspink/how-to-debug-code-efficiently-and-effectively-du107u9jh

Comment: @JamesRusso it is happening on this line  place_lats = place_lats.iloc[placeID]

Comment: @JamesRusso I have tried to identify the problem the ID column is an object type with letters and numbers do you think this i causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

`lats` does not exist anywhere in the function. Perhaps you meant `place_lats`

```
for placeID in range(lats.shape[0]):
        place_lat = lats.iloc[placeID]
        place_lng = lngs.iloc[placeID]
```

Comment: I have tried that and it still prints out the error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
for placeID in range(lats.shape[0]):
        place_lat = lats.iloc[placeID]
        place_lng = lngs.iloc[placeID]
```

to

```
for placeID in range(place_lats.shape[0]):
        place_lat = place_lats.iloc[placeID]
        place_lng = place_lngs.iloc[placeID]
```

As I stated in my original comment there is no variables `lats` or `lngs` defined in your code anywhere so it is failing on `for placeID in range(lats.shape[0]):` since you are trying to access an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're trying to use a variable, `lats`, that is not defined in your code. It's hard to tell precisely the fix without a better understanding of what your code is meant to do, but here's my guess:

```
for placeID in range(place_lats.shape[0]):
    place_lat = place_lats.iloc[placeID]
    place_lng = place_lngs.iloc[placeID]
```

replacing the use of `lats` with `place_lats`, which is defined. You could also change the declaration of your function to

`def get_nearest_dr(lats, lngs, dr_lats, dr_lngs):`

which would define `lats` and `lngs` in your code.

Comment: I have change the code to the above but am now getting an error numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'